# WSO2 API Manager - Strange No Matching Resource

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We got strange behavior on API Manager.

We updated our API's swagger file inside WSO2 Publisher. And we deployed it to our dev environment. It has only 2 resources. Everything was working, we can send requests to our gateway endpoint url and we can get responses as expected.

Then, we just wanted to add only a "s" letter to one resource's path. We updated the swagger in WSO2, also we deployed our API in our dev env again. Now, this resource doesn't work with new path name. It responses as shown in the picture. Other resource is working. But this not. Strangely, it works by using our service endpoint url directly. We found a solution by creating a new 1.0.1 version of same API. Now all resources are working. If we downgrade the version to 1.0.0, again this resource doesn't work.

I'm exactly sure there is no line shifting, missing character, missing tabs or etc. I see the resources on preview on API definition page.

What is the problem? Is this a bug? I think the 1.0.0 is storing on somewhere like cache or etc.[image: api reponse]

Comment: can you check the resources in the publisher whether It is got updated correctly or not?

Comment: @chashikajw exactly sure, I click edit, then I edit the swagger, and I click Update. And I see Success popup

Comment: What is your APIM version and how you got the pack?  Can you check whether it's updated in wso2am-3.2.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/yourAPi.xml synapse file as well?

Comment: Check the API  synapse file in <APIM-Home>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/ folder and see if the newly updated resource got updated successfully. Did you try restarting the server? When invoking the API call, did you use the correct API resource pathname? Did you try to invoke the new resource via CURL command?

Comment: @SarankiMagenthirarajah I downgraded the version to 1.0.0, deleted the 1.0.1 and restarted the server. and it works now. strange... thank you.. I hope, we will not need to restart after our every swagger updating